# Когда использовать многопоточность в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Как понять, когда необходимо использовать многопоточность в Java? Например, в каком-то многопользовательском сервисе.

Желательно с примерами.

Исключая варианты отрисовки (например, Java Swing) и ускорения работы программы.

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Всегда когда вы можете выполнить несколько операций независимых друг от друга параллельно. Условно если вам нужно выполнить функцию А и функцию Б каждая из которых занимает 3 секунды и функция А не зависит от результата функции Б то можно выполнить их параллельно

Comment: Если у вас нет проблем со скоростью работы вашей программы и ваша программа - это консольное или настольное приложение (не сервер), то вам многопоточность не нужна.

Comment: Если вы пишете многопользовательский сервис, то у вас скорее всего уже используется многопоточность, чтобы иметь возможность обработать запросы от 2х и более пользователей одновременно.

Answer (score 0):

В задачах c параллелизмом. Способ обработки множественных запросом одновременно.

Задача. Традиционный полный английский завтрак включает в себя бекон (традиционно back bacon), жареные, вареные яйца или омлет, жареные или приготовленные на гриле помидоры, жареные грибы, жареный хлеб или тосты с маслом и колбасы (также называемые «бангерами»). Также часто сюда включают чёрный пудинг и запечённые бобы и реже хашбраун ....

Подставьте себя на место повара и приготовьте завтрак. Если вы будите готовить последовательно в одном потоке, то яйца пожаренные в начале остынут пока приготовятся тосты или чай не заварится. ....

Я извиняюсь что не написал вам решения подобной задачи, она легко решается с Promise Future CompletableFuture... в Java и Tasks, async await C#.

Comment: `Исключая варианты отрисовки (например, Java Swing) и ускорения работы программы.` у автора нет проблем со скоростью, как я понимаю.

Comment: `Promise Future CompletableFuture... в Java и Tasks, async await C#` это все инструменты, они сами по себе ничего не решают. Есть же целые книги с различными конструкциями синхронизации.

Comment: Но вот приходится что-то придумывать.

Comment: Соласен перефразировал

Comment: @tym32167 на счет скорости ведь распаралеливание может наоборот замедлить процесс так что прирост скорости не гарантирован.

Comment: Не гарантирован, но какой тогда в ней смысл, если многопоточность замедляет программу?

Comment: под скоростью я имею ввиду скорость работы программы вцелом, а не скорость конкретного потока. Бывает, что при добавлении многопоточности отдельные потоки работают медленнее, но вцелом программа работает быстрее.

Comment: Не во всем есть явный смысл. Вы ищите решение задачи, но у вас не получилось. Смысл таков пока не сделаешь не узнаешь

Comment: Если пишете код, но при этом не знаете зачем вы его пишете, то у вас проблема с постановкой задачи :)

Comment: Как раз таки я знаю. Я решаю задачу ускорения конкретного куска программы, но многопоточность не дало её мне. Я не узнаю пока не напишу и не сравню

Comment: одна и таже задача сложения элементов массива с паралельностью и без может зависит от числа элементов в массиве. Так что зарание ответить на вопрос не всегда есть возможность.

Comment: Ну так это никак мне не противоречит. Если вы пытаетесь ускорить программу, но многопоточность ее только замедляет, то вы не будете использовать многопоточность в итоге. Не вижу тут проблем, или я потерял суть разговора.

Comment: Тот случай когда использовать или нет ответить не возможно не реализовав многопоточность. И смысл в реализации есть, то что он не нужен обоснованно а не голословно.

Comment: Это как быстрее ли подниматься на лифте или нет? Задача не однозначная так как нужно учитывать много параметров. Вы не узнаете пока все посчитаете.

Comment: мы говорим о разных вещах. Я говорю, что если нет проблем со скоростью - то скорее всего многопоточность вводить не нужно. Вы говорите, что если есть проблема со скоростью - то не факт, что многопоточнсть ее решит. Я согласен с обоими утверждениями, они не противоречат друг другу. Или мы о чем то другом беседуем?

Comment: В задаче о завтраке нет проблем со скоростью, есть проблемы с синхронностью. Если готовить последовательно то вы не решите задачу так как есть ожидание простой в готовке каждого блюда. В таких случаях нужно вводить многопоточность

Comment: Если честно, задача о завтраке по мне не имеет отношения к реальности. На практике если вам приходится заботиться о таймингах, то вы что то делаете не так. Можете подсказать более реалистичный пример именно из программирования?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110471/discussion-between-aziz-umarov-and-tym32167).